On Type II$_\infty$ factors
We know that any type II$_\infty$ factor can be decomposed as the tensor product between a type II$_1$ factor and some Type I$_\infty$factor $B(\mathcal{H})$. Is this decomposition unique? i.e. Could there be two such decompositions, so that the two Type II$_1$ factors, as well as the two Type I$_\infty$factors, are not isomorphic?

The type $I_\infty$ factor in the decomposition is unique. In the separable case, it is always $B(l^2)$. In general, you can still prove the uniqueness using semi-finite traces. The type $II_1$ factor is not unique. For example, take some $II_1$ factor $M$ and some $r > 0$ which is not in the fundamental group of $M$, then $M \otimes B(l^2) \simeq M^r \otimes B(l^2)$ but $M \not\simeq M^r$.

What does $M^r$ mean? Even if the Type II1 factors may not be unique, would they have the same properties? Say injectivity, hyperfiniteness, etc?

@Shadumu $M^r$ is the amplification of $M$. When $r$ is a natural number, $M^r$ is just $M \otimes \mathbb{M}_r$. More generally, $M^r$ is $p(M \otimes \mathbb{M}_n)p$, where $n$ is a natural number larger than or equal to $r$, and $p$ is a projection in $M \otimes \mathbb{M}_n$ of trace $r/n$. See section 4.2 of this notes for more details.

@Shadumu Injectivity and hyperfiniteness are equivalent for von Neumann algebras. And in the separable case there is only one (up to isomorphism) injective II$_1$ factor, usually denoted by $R$. $R$ has full fundamental group, that is to say, $R^r \simeq R$ for any $r > 0$. So that wouldn’t be a counterexample. In the nonseparable case there are hyperfinite II$_1$ factors whose fundamental groups are not full. Though in those cases you would still have $M$ is hyperfinite iff any (equivalently all) of its amplifications is hyperfinite.

Do all possible variants on the Type II$_1$ factor come from amplification? @David Gao

@Shadumu Did you mean “invariants” instead of “variants”? I’m not sure what “variants” would even mean here. And what do you mean by “come from”? They are certainly not all defined using amplification. If you meant whether all invariants on II$_1$ factors are stable under taking amplifications, then, I mean, it’s not always true that $M \simeq M^r$, so there has to be something that can change under amplification. Whether you count those as “invariants” depends on your definition. For example, even if $M$ is a group algebra, $M^r$ may not be. Does that count?

I mean to ask if all possible choices for the Type II1 factor in this decomposition can be obtained from amplification, or there are some other examples.

@Shadumu Oh, that’s what you meant. Amplifications are the only examples. If $M$ and $N$ are II$_1$ factors and $H$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, then $M \otimes B(H) \simeq N \otimes B(H)$ iff $M$ is an amplification of $N$ (or, equivalently, $N$ is an amplification of $M$).
